# Solana Token Swap Program - Error Given pool token amount results in zero trading tokens when performing Swap instruction

Tags: spl-token, token, swap

Hello I get an issue when I try to perform a swap on a token-swap program deployed on devnet.

> Error : Given pool token amount results in zero trading tokens

Transaction as an example : `21hYB5D2536E9jTbDzi9uRjCTso1sdAuiv6iJPksVHt12B158Tkx44jXA98yzSRRG7xCde3AehCzop9rd31cWKnV`

The data sent in the instruction seems to be correctly encoded and the accounts passed to the program also.

I assume that the Error is triggered at this step in the program processor but I am not sure and I don't clearly see what is wrong since I used the js bindings.

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/73673b6b306ad03086e1cb4a2ec87d220686c306/token-swap/program/src/processor.rs#L482

My code below :

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Connection, PublicKey, Transaction } from "@solana/web3.js";
import { getAssociatedTokenAddress, TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID } from "@solana/spl-token";
import { SWAP_HOST_FEE_ADDRESS } from "utils/swap/ids";



const SWAP_ID = new PublicKey("3JueWRCHJKKrgzqyLKcQ1dh82WUCKCdrA7tJq6U72Z6F");

const HOST_FEE = new PublicKey("HfoTxFR1Tm6kGmWgYWD6J7YHVy1UwqSULUGVLXkJqaKN");

export async function useSwap(
  connection: Connection,
  publicKey: PublicKey,
  tokenSwap: string,
  mintA: PublicKey,
  AmountA: number,
  mintB: PublicKey,
  MinimumAmountB: number,
  tokenAccountA: PublicKey,
  tokenAccountB: PublicKey,
  mintPoolToken: PublicKey,
  feeAccount: PublicKey,
  sendTransaction: any
) {
  console.log(
    `Starting Swap of ${AmountA} ${mintA.toString()} to ${MinimumAmountB} ${mintB.toString()}`
  );

  const Swap = require("@solana/spl-token-swap");
  console.log(Swap)

  const transaction = new Transaction();

  const tokenAccountSwapPubKey = new PublicKey(tokenSwap); //The Token Swap publicKey
  //Swap authority derived from program address
  const [swapAuthority, bump] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [tokenAccountSwapPubKey.toBuffer()],
    SWAP_ID
  );

  const userTokenAAccount = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(mintA, publicKey); //Token A user Account
  const userTokenBAccount = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(mintB, publicKey); //Token B user Account

  let instruction = Swap.TokenSwap.swapInstruction(
    tokenAccountSwapPubKey,
    swapAuthority,
    publicKey,
    userTokenAAccount,
    tokenAccountA,
    tokenAccountB,
    userTokenBAccount,
    mintPoolToken,
    feeAccount,
    HOST_FEE,
    SWAP_ID,
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    AmountA,
    MinimumAmountB
  )

  
  console.log(instruction);

  //@solana/spl-token-swap package is not up to date with the last js binding required to interact with the contract. Token mints should be provided in account keys.
  instruction.keys.splice(9,0,{pubkey: mintA, isSigner: false, isWritable: false},{pubkey: mintB, isSigner: false, isWritable: false})
  console.log(instruction);
  transaction.add(instruction);

  const {
    context: { slot: minContextSlot },
    value: { blockhash, lastValidBlockHeight },
  } = await connection.getLatestBlockhashAndContext();

  const signature = await sendTransaction(transaction, connection, {
    skipPreflight: true,
  });
  console.log(signature);

  await connection.confirmTransaction({
    blockhash,
    lastValidBlockHeight,
    signature,
  });

  return signature;
}
```

**EDIT :**

Data from the TokenSwap I try to use to swap.

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "isInitialized": 1,
    "bumpSeed": 255,
    "poolTokenProgramId": {
        "type": "Buffer",
        "data": [
            6,
            221,
            246,
            225,
            215,
            101,
            161,
            147,
            217,
            203,
            225,
            70,
            206,
            235,
            121,
            172,
            28,
            180,
            133,
            237,
            95,
            91,
            55,
            145,
            58,
            140,
            245,
            133,
            126,
            255,
            0,
            169
        ]
    },
    "tokenAccountA": {
        "type": "Buffer",
        "data": [
            153,
            37,
            89,
            220,
            190,
            173,
            169,
            89,
            119,
            65,
            99,
            240,
            125,
            28,
            172,
            16,
            240,
            1,
            221,
            169,
            166,
            140,
            59,
            215,
            202,
            183,
            117,
            154,
            252,
            205,
            10,
            106
        ]
    },
    "tokenAccountB": {
        "type": "Buffer",
        "data": [
            12,
            8,
            115,
            203,
            111,
            160,
            225,
            153,
            215,
            210,
            115,
            245,
            9,
            225,
            62,
            73,
            20,
            105,
            137,
            121,
            141,
            16,
            12,
            93,
            91,
            15,
            108,
            91,
            70,
            223,
            222,
            118
        ]
    },
    "tokenPool": {
        "type": "Buffer",
        "data": [
            23,
            247,
            77,
            135,
            112,
            231,
            187,
            243,
            160,
            59,
            79,
            136,
            51,
            194,
            97,
            19,
            77,
            80,
            140,
            193,
            22,
            81,
            35,
            77,
            29,
            104,
            71,
            157,
            196,
            47,
            180,
            77
        ]
    },
    "mintA": {
        "type": "Buffer",
        "data": [
            59,
            68,
            44,
            179,
            145,
            33,
            87,
            241,
            58,
            147,
            61,
            1,
            52,
            40,
            45,
            3,
            43,
            95,
            254,
            205,
            1,
            162,
            219,
            241,
            183,
            121,
            6,
            8,
            223,
            0,
            46,
            167
        ]
    },
    "mintB": {
        "type": "Buffer",
        "data": [
            6,
            155,
            136,
            87,
            254,
            171,
            129,
            132,
            251,
            104,
            127,
            99,
            70,
            24,
            192,
            53,
            218,
            196,
            57,
            220,
            26,
            235,
            59,
            85,
            152,
            160,
            240,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1
        ]
    },
    "feeAccount": {
        "type": "Buffer",
        "data": [
            18,
            36,
            93,
            153,
            18,
            6,
            183,
            36,
            146,
            142,
            94,
            101,
            118,
            141,
            35,
            189,
            211,
            30,
            172,
            178,
            192,
            82,
            125,
            17,
            180,
            174,
            97,
            128,
            216,
            14,
            132,
            72
        ]
    },
    "tradeFeeNumerator": {
        "type": "Buffer",
        "data": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
        ]
    },
    "tradeFeeDenominator": {
        "type": "Buffer",
        "data": [
            16,
            39,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
        ]
    },
    "ownerTradeFeeNumerator": {
        "type": "Buffer",
        "data": [
            5,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
        ]
    },
    "ownerTradeFeeDenominator": {
        "type": "Buffer",
        "data": [
            16,
            39,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
        ]
    },
    "ownerWithdrawFeeNumerator": {
        "type": "Buffer",
        "data": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
        ]
    },
    "ownerWithdrawFeeDenominator": {
        "type": "Buffer",
        "data": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
        ]
    },
    "hostFeeNumerator": {
        "type": "Buffer",
        "data": [
            20,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
        ]
    },
    "hostFeeDenominator": {
        "type": "Buffer",
        "data": [
            100,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
        ]
    },
    "curveType": 0,
    "curveParameters": {
        "type": "Buffer",
        "data": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let result = token_swap
        .swap_curve()
        .swap(
            to_u128(actual_amount_in)?,
            to_u128(source_account.amount)?,
            to_u128(dest_account.amount)?,
            trade_direction,
            token_swap.fees(),
        )
        .ok_or(SwapError::ZeroTradingTokens)?;
```

This issue is come from this part on solana program.

I think you should run the initialize function first before processing the swap function.

Comment: Hello thank you for your feedback. The publickey is coming from my parent component formatted as a string that is why I transform it to a PublicKey before using it. 
I previously created the token swap and initialize it, when I fetch its status the isInitialized property which is set to 1.

Comment: Could you please let me know the amountA and minimumtokenB? It seems you add 5 Wsol, and 15 USDC to the pool

Comment: Less than 1 for trial purpose

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the issue, as it was pointed out by @Doublers Kay the issue was coming from amountA and minimumtokenB. Those amount should be converted with appropriate token decimals to represent the correct amount in the program.

Example:

`AmountA = amountA * Math.pow(10,decimalsA)`

But know I have another issue I get the following error even if all of the Tokens are derived from Token Program. `TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA`

```
Full logs : `Program 3JueWRCHJKKrgzqyLKcQ1dh82WUCKCdrA7tJq6U72Z6F invoke [1]
Program log: Instruction: Swap
Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]
Program log: Instruction: TransferChecked
Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 6200 of 177498 compute units
Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success
Program log: Error: The provided token program does not match the token program expected by the swap
Program 3JueWRCHJKKrgzqyLKcQ1dh82WUCKCdrA7tJq6U72Z6F consumed 50853 of 200000 compute units
Program 3JueWRCHJKKrgzqyLKcQ1dh82WUCKCdrA7tJq6U72Z6F failed: custom program error: 0x18
```

Tx on Devnet for reference : `UbKuT73hCo4aLg6UgoDYaaVys6grYF7rJzsPLQoiF88Zh2mAjVx5gNKj89S397DDZPYNcV2qFFibjQXmpJD8C24`

Comment: hey did you ever find a solution to this? I have spent a few hours on this same issue myself and have not managed to find anything. I also checked owner ship of all related accounts passed in and they all match the correct ID afaict. 

If you have a solution I would be very very very grateful.

Comment: my best guess is that copying the program from testnet or devnet did something strange where perhaps token-2022 is being used?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the owner trade fee from swap pool, then I successfully performed swap instruction with following params:

```
TokenSwap.swapInstruction(
    tokenSwap.tokenSwap,
    tokenSwap.authority,
    userTransferAuthority.publicKey,
    userAccountA,
    tokenSwap.tokenAccountA,
    tokenSwap.tokenAccountB,
    userAccountB,
    tokenSwap.poolToken,
    tokenSwap.feeAccount,
    null,
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    tokenSwap.swapProgramId,
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    swapAmountIn,
    swapAmountOut,
  ),
),
```